# Is this React Forms Example really valid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Based on the [React Forms documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), I am wondering why the following example is valid ?

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input 
            type="text" 
            value={this.state.value} 
            onChange={this.handleChange} 
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

As `this.setState` is **asynchronous**, you could have a `change` and a `submit` event that follow each other, so you would obtain the following senario : :

1. `change event` emitted
2. `submit event` emitted
3. `handleChange` is called, so `this.setState` is called, as it's **asynchronous** the state is not updated immediately
4. `handleSubmit` is called, `this.state.name` doesn't refer to the last value typed into the input field as the state update hasn't been applied yet.
5. The state is updated

So if my understanding is correct, in this example, the `handleSubmit` is not guaranteed to revrieve the last value typed into the input field ?

Comment: I think I got it, as the state is the single source of truth for the controlled components, the input value is actually the value of `this.state.name`, so when you submit the form, the form values could be retrieve from the `state`